# Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function with QTest

Tags: c++, qt

I am developing a Qt project with Qt creator, all works fine, but when i came to the unit testing part using QTest, after compilation I get the error "Invalid parameter passed to C run-time function".

Can anyone help me to find the source of the problem?
Is it due to the use of `cstdio` functions or has it something to do with the `.pro` configuration?

This is a test method I implemented and did not work:

```
void TestFichier::testLoad()
{
    Fichier a;
    a.load("input.txt");
    FILE *f=fopen("input.txt","rb");
    int c;
    int i,*tab=a.getHexValues();
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
        c=fgetc(f);
    fclose(f);
    QCOMPARE(tab[2],c);
}
```

Fichier is a class I created with a method `load`.

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN fgetc documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7sskzc1.aspx) states:

> If [the parameter] stream is NULL, fgetc and fgetwc invoke the invalid parameter
>   handler, as described in [Parameter Validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksazx244.aspx).

So you should check if `fopen` returns `NULL`, and in that case, find the type of error with `errno`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, your problem is that you make some errors while working with dynamical memory.
For example, you can use pointers to unallocated memory, or so. Check your code at `getHexValues()` method.